# How to make a link that will go up one directory?

Tags: php

I want to create a link that will take the user up one directory no matter where they are.

```
<a href="<?php echo dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); ?>">Back</a>
```

This works well except if the user is at `mysite.com/some/page/randompage.php` I would like the link to take them back to `mysite.com/some/page/` instead of `mysite.com/some/`.

Any simple way to go about this or will I have to use regex?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to always be a full URI that is specified rather than a relative one?

Comment: up one directory from `/some/page/randompage.php` is `/some/`, not `/some/page/`.

Comment: And `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is at least `/some/page/index.php` or what ever the index file is, but not `/some/page/`. So `dirname(...)` should work. **BUT** @Mikes answer is the easiest way to go up.

Answer (score 0):

If a relative solution works for you, there's always something like this:

```
<a href="../">Link Text </a>
```

or

```
<a href="../../">Link Text </a>
```